# Rename [deviant-art] to [deviantart]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

The tag for [deviant-art](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deviant-art) should be renamed to [deviantart](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deviantart) to reflect the site's [official name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DeviantArt).

It's a tiny tag with just a [single question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/30020/how-can-i-view-the-keywords-on-a-piece-of-art-from-deviantart), but I can't think of any reason not to use the site's proper name.

Comment: Just create the new tag and remove the old one.

Comment: @Rubén: Not possible, because the duplicate tag preventer keeps mortals like us from creating `deviantart` when `deviant-art` already exists. This is something a Moderator needs to handle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is all set.  I think the new tag got lost somewhere in the shuffle, so I created it and added it.

Comment: At some point the tag wiki got lost. I've made a [suggested-edit](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/91332) to transfer it over.