# Please rename [research-gate] to [researchgate]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

The tag [research-gate](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/research-gate) should be renamed to [researchgate](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/researchgate) better to reflect the site's official name.

It's a tiny tag with just a single question, [How to “unfollow” people on ResearchGate](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/47597/how-to-unfollow-people-on-researchgate) but I can't think of any reason not to use the site's proper name. The network referred to is clearly that at https://www.researchgate.net/:

[image: Two examples of ResearchGate]

and

[image: Third example of ResearchGate]

Ref: [Rename [deviant-art] to [deviantart]](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4196/rename-deviant-art-to-deviantart])

Comment: Makes sense. Given there's one question, you could just retag it and copy-paste the tag excerpt...

Comment: Oh, I forgot about similar-tag prohibition.

Comment: It's renaming a tag, which is what a retag-request is.

Comment: That's an awful narrow reading of the guidance. Whatever. I'm sure the mods can work it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is done

```
updating post history, 2 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 1 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
removing/renaming old tag, 1 rows affected
tag remapping of [researchgate] and [research-gate] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
0 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
0 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Tag Synonym research-gate -> researchgate was approved!
```